# Image View Flicker when resizing on Touch events

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

**Requirement:**

To create a list of image view on top of each other which can be resized(only heightwise) on touch events. Resizing one view should not resize other view.

**Issue:**

I created a relative layout and I aligned my first child (image view) to the bottom of the relative layout using `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.` I add more image views above the bottom image view. I have also implemented image resize on touch event as below. The problem is that the image view flickers as I resize on `ACTION_MOVE`. If I align my first child(image View) to top this doesn't happen. I believe this is because of the `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` being called on touch event. Not sure how to fix this.

**Feedback:**

Also want to get feedback on this approach for meeting the requirements.I am not sure is performance is a downside in this approach.

Any help is Appreciated. Thanks!

```
public class StackLayoutActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int mActivePointerId;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private ImageView imageViewTwo;
private ImageView imageViewOne;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stack_layout);
    init();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void init() {
    int imageTwoHeight = 250;
    int imageOneHeight = 400;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageTwoParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, imageTwoHeight);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageOneParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, imageOneHeight);

    imageViewTwo = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageViewTwo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    imageViewTwo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha));
    imageViewTwo.setId(View.generateViewId());
    imageViewTwo.setOnTouchListener(new ImageTwoTouchListener());

    imageViewOne = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageOneParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    imageViewOne.setLayoutParams(imageOneParams);
    imageViewOne.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    imageViewOne.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));
    imageViewOne.setId(View.generateViewId());
    imageViewOne.setOnTouchListener(new ImageOneTouchListener());
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.container);

    imageTwoParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, imageViewOne.getId());
    layout.addView(imageViewOne);
    layout.addView(imageViewTwo, imageTwoParams);
}


private class ImageOneTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);


                final float dist = y - mLastTouchY;

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = imageViewOne.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height -= dist;
                imageViewOne.setLayoutParams(lp);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

private class ImageTwoTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                final float dist = y - mLastTouchY;

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;


                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = imageViewTwo.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height -= dist;
                imageViewTwo.setLayoutParams(lp);

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the flickering issue by removing the modification to Last touch positions in ACTION_MOVE. Removed the below code from ACTION_MOVE block

```
mLastTouchX = x;
mLastTouchY = y;
```